# Has the sign of the quartic SM Higgs coupling ever been measured?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, higgs, large-hadron-collider

I know that for the SM we assume that the quartic coupling of the Higgs $\lambda_H>0$ due to vacuum stability, but in principle for $\lambda_H<0$ vacuum stability could still be safe if we have some non-renormalisable interaction (e.g. $\lambda_6 (H^\dagger H)^3$) coming from some large energy scale $\Lambda \gg m_\text{EW}$.

I know that the Higgs sector is not too strongly constraint, but in principle one should get the sign of the $\lambda_H$ coupling by looking at the interference diagrams (one-loop and tree-level to get an odd power of $\lambda_H$) $h\rightarrow b\bar{b}$ decay.

Has some experiment already confirmed such a interference process?

Comment: maybe this proposal includes the above  https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.04240

Comment: Ideed thanks a lot. So to summarise in this analysis they found from the interference of $gg\rightarrow hh$ (top triangle diagram and box diagram) at 68% C.L. $−0.8<\frac{\lambda_H}{\lambda_{H,\text{SM}}}<6.6$, which could still indicate negative $lambda_H$ although it is not preferred.